# Salesforce - Siblings list

Tags: related-list

Is there a way to show sibling records that share a lookup relationship?

Eg, An Application object has a lookup to the Location code.

On the Application object instance detail page I want to see a list that shows all other Applications that share that same Location.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it will need to be an embedded Visualforce page rather than a related list. A simple example would be:

Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Application__c" extensions="SiblingsExtCtrl"> 
  <apex:outputField value="{!Application__c.Location__c}" rendered="false"/>
  <apex:pageBlock title="Siblings">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!siblings}" value="{!sibling}">
      <apex:column value="{!sibling.Id}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!sibling.Name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class SiblingsExtCtrl
{
   public List<Application__c> siblings {get; set;}
   public SiblingsExtCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController std)
   {
       Application__c app=(Application__c) std.getRecord();
       siblings=[select id, name from Application__c
                 where Location__c=:app.Location__c
                   and id!=:app.id];
   }
}
```

There may be the odd typo in there, but hopefully you get the picture.  You'll probably need to do some styling to replicate the related list look and feel as closely as you can.